# Mysql if else statement for table row field

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
|id | enable | min | max |
|------------------------|
|1  | true   | 4   |  10 |
|2  | false  | 5   |  23 |
|3  | true   | 6   |  45 |
|------------------------|
```

What do i want?

1. select rows that "min" and "max" are between 2 and 30.
2. The above condition applies only to the rows where the "enable" field is **true** not for **false**

## output

Given the condition of the above output have to like below

```
|id | enable | min | max |
|------------------------|
|1  | true   | 4   |  10 |
|------------------------|
```

**Sorry for bad grammar**

Comment: It's proably better to use 1 or 0 in a `TINYINT` column instead of a string-type "boolean" value. MySQL can then do `WHERE enable` instead of having to do the clunky `WHERE enable='true'`.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT ID, ENABLE, MIN, MAX
FROM
YOUR_TABLE
WHERE ENABLE = 'TRUE' AND MIN >= 2 AND MAX <= 30;
```

Comment: thanks for answer but i want this condition "MIN >= 2 AND MAX <= 30" run  for only true "enable" fields not false, first check if "enable" field is true then set MIN >= 2 AND MAX <= 30 condition

Comment: By combining `ENABLE = 'TRUE'` condition using `AND` with MIN and MAX conditions, they will apply only to records with `TRUE` values.

Comment: Watch for case here. Depending on collation settings `TRUE` might not be the same as `true`.